# Flask route wildcards not resolving direct links

Tags: python, flask

I tried to combine all my routes into 1 but now I can't resolve direct links:

On the client side we introduced react-router so I don't need all these routes anymore:

```
@app.route('/')
def list():
    return render_helper('index.html')


@app.route('/review/<queue_id>', methods=['GET'])
def bulk_review(queue_id=''):
    return render_helper('index.html')


@app.route('/metrics')
def metrics():
    return render_helper('index.html')
```

I changed it to:

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index():
    return render_helper('index.html')
```

But now when I try to access: `/review/id` that path is not available.

Is there a way to combine all these routes into 1?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `path` to the function:

```
def index(path = ''):
```